# Only one row is returned from SQLite in IOs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to pull the rows from my SQLite and for some reason only the first row is being pulled out. Here is my code:

```
-(void)pullNewDataFromSqlite {

    NSLog(@"pulling new data");

    NSString *fetch_sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@", tableName];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *my_sqlfile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];


    if(sqlite3_open([my_sqlfile UTF8String], &my_dbname) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"pulling new data, %@", fetch_sql);
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(my_dbname));


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(my_dbname, [fetch_sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {


        int numberOfColumns = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
        //sqlite3_


        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"NEW SQLITE ROW");

            int sdcount = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            NSLog(@"NEW SQLITE ROW number, %d", sdcount);


            for(int a = 1; a < numberOfColumns; a++) {

                char *field = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, a);


                NSString *fieldVal = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field];
                NSString *formatout = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", fieldVal];


                //match first column with first array

                //adding each column info to the array in order

                //user id
                if(a == 1) {
                    NSLog(@"a is 1 and the value of the user id is %@", formatout);
                    [userIdsArray addObject:formatout];
                }

                //name
                if(a == 2) {
                    NSLog(@"a is 2 and the value of the name id is %@", formatout);
                    [namesArray addObject:formatout];
                }

                //picture
                if(a == 3) {
                    NSLog(@"a is 3 and the value of the pic id is %@", formatout);
                    [picturesArray addObject:formatout];
                }




            }
            //"call sqlite3_finalize to clean up the memory used for the statement, then we return the data."
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        }

    }
        }

    [self closeDB];

    if(count < [userIdsArray count]) {
        grabFollowers = YES;
    }

    count = [userIdsArray count];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Also it does show the other 2 rows but for some reason it shows blank.

Comment: Have you used an SQLite data browser to verify what the contents of your db is prior to running a Select * query?

Comment: Why do you log a message stating that you couldn't prepare the statement before you actually prepare the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `sqlite3_finalize` inside the `while` loop.

You must not call it until you have stepped through all rows.

Answer (score 0):

change while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)  to while (sqlite3_step(statement) <= SQLITE_ROW)

Comment: Why what is the different should't it be equal to the amount less than will stop it early?